# substitute parts of a command in a bash script with arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, arguments

I am very new to programing, especially in bash.

I often run the same long command filled with many arguments each day but with different file names and one other argument, the bulk of the string remains the same. This is the case for Clonezilla server.

I want to be able to run a script that only asks for the for the portions I want to change, then substitutes those values into the original string and pass it along to the shell.

For example:

I have a set of file names: a.img b.img c.img

the command I run: `drbl-ocs -b -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -x -j2 -sc0 -p poweroff --clients-to-wait <number value here> -l en_US.UTF-8 startdisk multicast_restore <name of file> nvme0n1`

My goal is to be able to type: sudo sh myscript.sh arga argb

where "arga" is a number that replaces `<number value here>` and "argb" replaces `<name of file>` in the above string.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Put it in a file and change `<number value here>` to `"$1"` and `<name of file>` to `"$2"` ?

Comment: @123, you should add an answer

Comment: @glennjackman I'm sure there must be a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The command line arguments to a script can be found in the *positional parameters*, parameters whose names are positive integers.

```
#!/bin/sh

drbl-ocs -b -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -x -j2 -sc0 \
         -p poweroff --clients-to-wait "$1" -l en_US.UTF-8 \
         startdisk multicast_restore "$2" nvme0n1
```

Comment: Just a note: in many cases, you could use a shell function instead of bothering with a script file; but you can't use  `sudo` on shell functions, so in this case a script is the way to go.